# Схема управления мотор колесами

Tags: arduino

Хочу сделать контроллер для мотор колеса, програмируемий на ардуино. Придумал схему нарисовал. Собрал макет вроде работает на моторе от винчестера, но один из двух средний такт очень слабый причем блокирует даже лампочку подключенную к управлению. Подключал мотор схему к мотор колесу от моно колеса (когда камеру клеил) два шага нормально дергает один только пытается.
Подскажите где в схеме проблема. Транзисторы IRFZ44N.

макет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3д рендор для красоты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код управления

```
    int A = 4;
int B = 5;
int C = 6;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

pinMode(A,OUTPUT);
pinMode(B,OUTPUT);
pinMode(C,OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(A,LOW);
digitalWrite(B,LOW);
digitalWrite(C,LOW);

}

int delayTimeout = 0;
int delayStep = 30;
void pinABC(int pin)
{
  if(pin!=A)  digitalWrite(A,LOW);
    if(pin!=B)  digitalWrite(B,LOW);
      if(pin!=C)  digitalWrite(C,LOW);
      delay(delayTimeout);
      digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
}


void loop() {

  for(int i = 0;i<50;i++)
  {
  pinABC(A);
  delay(delayStep);
  pinABC(B);
  delay(delayStep);
  pinABC(C);
  delay(delayStep);
  }
/*реверс
   for(int i = 0;i<50;i++)
  {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  pinABC(C);
  delay(delayStep);
  pinABC(B);
  delay(delayStep);
  pinABC(A);
  delay(delayStep);
  }*/

}
```

Вот схема, мосфетов в програме нет, по етому вставил обычные транзисторы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Паял схему на других транзисторах та же проблема.

Comment: Чем такой рендер делать, лучше бы принципиальную схему приложили. Можно, например, в бесплатной программе от https://fritzing.org/ нарисовать

Comment: «причем блокирует даже лампочку подключенную к управлению» — что за лампочка? Ее нет в схеме.

Comment: Вечером дорисую, просто к управляющим проводам от ардуины прцепил 3 лампочки две в свою очередь якрко моргают одна ели ели вспихивает

Comment: Которая, A, B или C?

Comment: не работает B, не понятно схема по кругу подключена, первое пличо со вторым втророе с третим трете с первым, кок ошыбка вообще могла появиться. ьолько в одном пличе.

Comment: Стоит попробовать полностью отключить транзисторы, оставив только лампочки. Если проблема останется, то дело или в коде или в поврежденной ардуине. Если исчезнет — перепроверять подключение транзисторов

Comment: Для справки подал 12 вольт на силовую часть и сжог ардуино. Обломно, модет кто знает есть ли готовые модули только силовой части?